# How do critical hits work with static monster damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, critical-hit

If I use static damage from monsters, how do I calculate the value on critical hits? I can't just double the value, because that includes the static modifier. Should I recalculate the damage on the fly (so, if the monster usually has (7) d8 + 3, I make it (11) 2d8 + 3)? That's kind of pain in the ass. Or do the monsters not double their static damage on critical hits and only get the benefit of the guaranteed hit? Alternatively, I could decide that I roll on crits.

Are there official rules the govern this?

Comment: Actually I have retracted the duplicate vote, you are asking what the rules say on this. Leaving it as related: [Handling critical hits easily when using average damage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124309/33707)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### The Dungeon Master's Guide has rules for handling this case:

On the [Monsters and Critical Hits](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#MonstersandCriticalHits) section (DMG page 248), it states what to do in the case of a monster critical hit when using average damage:

> When the monster scores a critical hit, roll all the damage dice associated with the hit and add them to the average damage. For example, if a goblin normally deals 5 (1d6 + 2) slashing damage on a hit and scores a critical hit, it deals 5 + 1d6 slashing damage.

So the suggestion is simply to roll the damage dice and then add the average damage. In your case, the damage of (7) d8 + 3 simply becomes 1d8+7 when a mosnter scores a critical hit.

Comment: Nice find! Also good to know that I've been doing this "right" all along (when I use average damage, that is).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I need to re-read all the books again to catch all these pieces!

Answer (score 11):

### Are there official rules on this?

[Yes, per Sdjz's answer.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/159621/22566).
But it requires a die roll.
You can do it without any dice rolling if you like.

#### What have I seen done that is fast and simple?

A critical hit when using average damage is "Max roll +1"
If I am doing 1d4, it becomes 5 + modifier.
If I am doing 1d6, it  becomes 7 + modifier.

Easy to keep track of in one's head:
*When monster rolls a "Critical Hit, I add one to the max die value"*
... you have to add the modifier anyway, critical hit or not.

No die roll required.

What do I do? I roll the dice.  I got addicted to the dice rolling bit when I started playing, so even though *the above method is faster*, I still roll the dice.

---

<sub>As the number of dice rolled increase, you run into the matter of even number versus odd number.  If monster damage is 2dx, 4dx, 6dx just double the average + modifier.  If you have an odd number of dice, 3dx, 5dx, it's *double the average +1* + modifier ... because the posted average in the books rounds fractions down</sub>

Comment: I think I prefer to roll as well, but this is a clever and convenient way to shortcut things for the sake of simplicity